# Rect tool showing offset object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rect

Difficult to explain but when I click on rect tool it displays a grey patch area offset from the actual game object which I'm unable to interact with or change, I notice that pressing play causes the grey object to fall continuously. Other Game objects do not behave in the same way. Want to understand what it was and how I could remove it. Please see the image below.

[image: Rect tool offset circle]

[image]

Comment: Probably a component or a nested a child in one of your hierarchy objects. Couple of easy ways to find it - 1) try clicking on it, 2) disable all objects on scene and turn them back on individually to see when it pops up.

Comment: A rect is usually relative to it's parent object. In prefab mode there is no such parent object so Unity usually assumes a Canvas. Looks like your prefab simply doesn't have the coordinates `0,0,0` in it's Transform component

Comment: @ArmanPapikyan I disabled all objects even the Ftyres object and it still appears. Clicking on it just takes the focus away from the ftyres object an you can no longer see it.

Comment: @derHugo I have updated the question and from the second screenshot, i have made all game objects invisible but kept the ftyres highlighted. in my Transform, i have set the position to 0,0,0. but I'm still seeing this offset image. At this point, my only option would be to recreate this prefab as it doesnt behave as it should.

Comment: Check your positions and offsets! Is it possible that this circle is the pivot point off your root object? Meaning the child objects have a strange local position (= position displayed in Inspector = offset relative to parent object)

Comment: @derHugo you were right, all the children positions were offset from the parent object, i have changed this accordingly and now all the objects are in the same position as the circle. Would that mean this circle being their is expected behaviour? Would all game objects have a greyed out circle as its anchor that you cant interact with?

Comment: Only in the rect mode I guess .. you should not use the rect mode except for UI .. use the usual Handles and you would have seen this right away from the beginning ...